# Can we have multiple (more than two) partial classes in c#?

Tags: c#, partial-classes

Suppose there are 3 members in a team and all of them wants to work on a same class. So in this case can we use more than 2 partial class in c#?

Comment: Thats solving a problem by creating more problems. Also partial classes are iffy at best and a major code smell. i suggest using git or some reliable version control

Comment: Was it easier for you to post this question than to try it? Honestly it would take 30 seconds.

Comment: Unrelated to partial classes but still related to the context of your question - there is a tool for real time code collaboration called [Visual Studio Live Share](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/). I haven't tried it, but might be worth checking out.

Comment: @TheGeneral I use partial classes sometimes when I need to implement multiple interfaces, one for every interface. I feel it is a easy way to keep the methods grouped.

Comment: @Magnus there are legitimate use cases indeed, however my point (and opinion) was multi-developer access is not one of them, its just asking for problems. Its using the wrong tool for the wrong job (using a langauge feature as a productivity tool, likely to introduce subtle mistakes, broken code, duplication, bloat, and and just completely unnecessary with version control systems. Its seems this has probably been a part of the documentation since version one and entirely fishy (note angst not directed at you)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create more than 2 `Partial classes`. (Source [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods))

**According to Docs:**

> When working on large projects, spreading a class over separate files enables multiple programmers to work on it at the same time.

**Working Example**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.PrintMessage1();
        foo.PrintMessage2();
        foo.PrintMessage3();
    }
}

public partial class Foo
{
    public void PrintMessage1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo1");
    }  
}

public partial class Foo
{
    public void PrintMessage2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo2");
    }
}

public partial class Foo
{
    public void PrintMessage3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo3");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am surprised the documentation says that at all, its the worst use case in the history of partial classes

Comment: IMO partial classes are best used when automatic code generation is involved. As @TheGeneral mentioned, that is the worst use case.

Comment: @TheGeneral could you provide a link showcasing the shortcomings and pitfalls of multiple programmers working concurrently with the same class?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `Partial classes` may contain conflicts at run time.

Comment: You can refer this also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157958/what-pitfalls-are-inherent-in-using-partial-classes

Answer (score 3):

I would not introduce partial classes, to be able to cowork with other developers. A good practice is to use some kind of version control like [Git](https://git-scm.com/), [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/index.de.html) and [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019). Just to name a few.

Version Control serves multiple [purposes](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/basics/why-use-version-control):

- Helping you collaborate. E.g. with merge features.
- Store your Versions (pretty obvious)
- Restore old Versions and Snapshots (also called Commits)
- Keep track of your changes. Review File histories, and see who wrote which code.
- Backup

Also note, that any Version Control greatly benefits from Merge Tools. These are used to merge multiple File Versions - *often submitted by different developers* - into one file. It is often refered to as solving [merge-conflicts](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/advanced-topics/merge-conflicts) in Version Control.

#### Jumpstart into Version Control

To give you a little jumpstart, maybe try the following combination:

- [GitExtensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/)
- [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/features.html)

Use GitExtensions as a graphical interface for the git Version Control. Use Meld to solve merge conflicts.

---

#### Summary

To use Version Control in Software development is a major bestpractice, which greatly helps in project management, agility, collaboration and documentation.

> To be honest, I've never been working anywhere, where we did not use this nor do I know anyone who didn't. So even though, I'm not aware of the OP's background, I'd still suggest to give it a shot.
>
> Also: Even the *Kings of collaboration* - developers working together on big opensource projects, work with Version Control. Mostly git.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but a good explanation why not to use that workflow. Not sure if +1 or not ... eh, here you go ;p

Comment: @nilsK thanks a lot. Anyway according to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) _don't do this_ is a valid answer :)